# WMI Invalid class but "WMI repository is consistent"

Tags: windows, 64-bit, wmi

On my Windows 10 Pro 64-bit PC, when I go to WMI Control in Computer Management under "Services and Applications" and select "More Actions" -> Properties, it displays the following:-

Failed to initialize all required WMI classes.

Win32_Processor: WMI: Invalid class

Win32_WMISetting: WMI: Invalid class

Security information: Successful
Win32_OperatingSystem: WMI Invalid class

However, when I run command "winmgmt /verifyrepository" in an elevated command prompt (as advised in many web-pages) it reports: "WMI repository is consistent" which, I'm led to believe means the WMI Repository is NOT corrupt. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue creep up on a few of our corporate devices:

winmgmt /verifyrepository - responds repository is consistent

but in wmimgmt.msc WMI Control Properties we can see the errors:

- Failed to initialize all required WMI classes.
- Win32_Processor: WMI: Invalid class
- Win32 WMISettmg WMI Invalid class
- Security information Successful
- Win32_OperatingSystem WMI Invalid class

Solution was discovered we needed to restore WMI Namespace class data, and found we diddnt need to research any needed .mof files by using the mofcomp and regSvr32 commands below. Note the commands are listed along with a restart of the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service and gpupdate to test for any errors. Also note in several cases we had to run through the commands a few times until WMI and RSOP errors resolve.

*** Recompile Mof files for WMI errors ***

1. run from elevated cmd prompt:

- cd C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
- for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s
- for %i in (*.dll) do regSvr32 -s %i
- net stop winmgmt /y
- net start winmgmt
- gpupdate /force

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution was ran `winmgmt /resetrepository` 
in the cmd with administrator privilege.
About the cause of the problem according to this information source is because Antivirus scanning cause corruption in WMI https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/wmi-missing-or-failing-wmi-providers-or-invalid-wmi-class/ba-p/375485